# Devuelve array inesperado con agreggate mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Hola tengo esta consulta en mongo que es un aggregate y me esta retornando un array de mas el cual me esta causando problemas con la estructura de mi objeto:

```
aggregate([
            {
                $set: {
                    "branchOffices.specialties": {
                        $map: {
                            input: "$branchOffices.specialties",
                            as: "me",
                            in: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$$me",
                                    cond: {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$$this.name",
                                            filterAppointment
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

y me esta respondiendo asi, con un array de mas, el cual lo dejo a la vista la parte donde el  código esta comentado:

```
{
           
            "branchOffices": [
                {
                    "name": "Dávila",
                    "address": "Av. Recoleta 464, Recoleta, Región Metropolitana",
                    "sector": "norte",
                    "specialties": [
                        [ // este es el array inesperado
                            {
                                "name": "Broncopulmonar Adulto",
                                "appointments": [
                                    {
                                        "date": "2022-04-19",
                                        "time": "09:45",
                                        "link": "https://www.davila.cl/reserva-de-hora/",
                                        "specialist": "Dr. Maria Pastora Chabla Zeas",
                                        "_id": "625db6af507593461f6c852f"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Lo que espero que retorne es algo así, que solo tenga los objetos y no con el array

```
{
"branchOffices": [
                {
                    "name": "Dávila",
                    "address": "Av. Recoleta 464, Recoleta, Región Metropolitana",
                    "sector": "norte",
                    "specialties": [
                         // sin este array
                            {
                                "name": "Broncopulmonar Adulto",
                                "appointments": [
                                    {
                                        "date": "2022-04-19",
                                        "time": "09:45",
                                        "link": "https://www.davila.cl/reserva-de-hora/",
                                        "specialist": "Dr. Maria Pastora Chabla Zeas",
                                        "_id": "625db6af507593461f6c852f"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
               
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

cabe destacar que filterAppointment es un valor como parametro y se espera por parte del cliente.

gracias..

Comment: Prueba agregando un `{ $unwind: "$branchOffices.specialties" }` al final del pipeline del aggregate

Comment: Te funcionó lo que te sugerí?

Comment: @Pipe agregue esto y no funciona: {   
                $set: {
                    "branchOffices.specialties": {     ....
                    }
                }
            },
            {$unwind: "$branchOffices.specialties"},

Comment: Si la respuesta que espera no es muy grande, entonces puede hacerlo `por código` luego de la consulta. Es decir desde `nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma podría ser, usando `$arrayElemAt` así:

```
aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "branchOffices.specialties": { 
        $arrayElemAt: [ 
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$branchOffices.specialties",
              as: "me",
              in: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$$me",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.name",
                      "hola"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }, 
          0
        ]  
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Para indicarle que del resultado del filtro solo tome el primer elemento del array eliminando así el array padre.